# PhpStorm SQL code autocomplete

Tags: sql, phpstorm

I have used *PhpStorm 10*, but recently they released a new version. In PhpStorm 10 it was very comfortable to autocomplete SQL code. I could start typing the column name and autocompletion continued my code.

At the new version (*PhpStorm 2016.2.1*) you have to start typing with the table prefix before column name, that is not very convenient.

Maybe someone knows how change this option, that I could start typing column name without the table prefix to autocomplete my SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem. You have to do next steps:

- Press `Alt+Ctrl+S` or `File -> Settings`
- Then you go to `Languages & Frameworks` and open `SQL Dialects` tab.
- There will be your project `File/Directory` window and you have to change
  `<Generic>` dialect to your current project dialect. In my case it is a `MySQL` dialect.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I struggled for a year, lost it across all projects a year ago. I enabled it on some individual projects, but lost track of where and how. Dude, thank you very much!!!
P.S. Damn PhpStorm that, after updates, changes settings on its own and gets slower with each passing year..